# I need help identifying a special kind of coupling

Tags: machine-design, machine-elements, coupling

I found this switchable coupling in Rollof/Matek machine elements, i have never seen this kind of coupling before.

[image]

According to the dutch edition its name is:

> Tweevlakskoppeling

Which literally means *Two-surface coupling*

After some research on the web i couldn't find any reliable information, i thought the translation is wrong, then I checked the original edition in german, apparently, the name is correct. The original edition:

[image]

Can someone identify this coupling?

Comment: Okay, you have a mechanical fingerplate clutch with a fussy throwout bearing. Why the fussy bearing? It would let you have zero hold-in force against the bearing.  I tried for an hour to find one like it and couldn't.

Comment: @PhilSweet I really appreciate your effort, i guess this is just a concept, and there is yet no commercial prototype exist.

Comment: Either that or they quit making them 50 years ago. I can see one of these being connected to a great big hand lever on an old sawmill drive.

Answer (score 1):

Look for overrunning clutch or power transmission elements.

[image]

[image]

You may find a lot of info in Ringspann site:
[Ringspann power transmission section](https://www.ringspann.com/en/products/freewheels/complete-freewheels/for-bolting-to-the-face/complete-freewheels-fkh)

Or here:
[Ringspann catalogue](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/25781671/power-transmission-ringspann)

Comment: I checked the websites thank you, but this seems whole other mechanism, i looked at the catalogue, the coupling (mine) follows the same mechanism as a regular car clutch, the only difference is the locking system number 10 in my sketch, however in your links, this kind of locking system doesn't exist or at least i don't see it.